# New users can post urls (which they shouldn't be able to - I think)

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I'm a new user and noticed a bug when posting a problem of mine on Stack Overflow.

If you have less than 10 points (or whatever it was called) it says you can't post any urls. As I really wanted to use the urls as demonstration I thought I'd remove a "t" from "http".

So instead of posting this: http://www.website.com/, I posted this: htp://www.website.com/

When then looking at my question I asked I noticed the urls was working and actually transformed to urls with "http" instead of "htp" which I originally typed in. Why? Well, I think at the moment you are auto-correcting bad url inputs or something like that.

Comment: You can still write the URL in your post. If you have the reputation then they will change to links, if not then most of the time a user who reads that post and does have the reputation will edit the post for you to turn the text links into actual links. (Unless they are just spam, of course, but they will be dealt with separately).

Comment: By allowing links, it allows new users to post image without having to upload. They just post a link to where it's uploaded somewhere else. On a side note, preventing image uploads for new users prevents spam accounts uploading random crap, like gore and stuff which costs Stack Exchange money for bandwidth and storage which would be a pain to delete manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users are allowed to post two urls per post, but not more.  That's why two of your links were adjusted, but two weren't.  The privilege you listed is to allow more than 2 links per post.

Also note that in this context it appears that the links don't actually need to be links; you're showing the links because they themselves are what people are interested in.  By enclosing them in backticks `like this` you can make that clearer to the reader.  I've adjusted the links in your post accordingly.